# Sharepoint - Integrate c# application

Tags: c#, sharepoint

iam new to sharepoint. I have an application created in C#. Now i have to upload to sharepoint portal server and need to create a link in documents tab which will open this application.

Comment: I don't understand the question... do you mean you created a document-based application, and you want to be able to use your application to edit documents in a sharepoint list, just like how you can do with MS Office documents?

Comment: No. I have to create a new link in documents tab. On clicking that link has to open the page which i have created in asp.net, C#. Newly created page has just a combo box

Comment: Please provide more details in your question. You didn't even mention you're talking about ASP.NET. Which version of SharePoint do you have? Which "documents tab" are you talking about? Is the ASP.NET page supposed to run within SharePoint, or as a standalone? Do you need to insert the link automatically or by hand?

Answer (score 2):

If you are simply trying to show the contents of one web page inside of SharePoint then you can use a "Content Editor Web Part".  You set the URL of the web part and the web page is displayed inside of an iFrame on your SharePoint page.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an existing C# solution, you could either put that inside a web part or create an application page for it:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231581.aspx